# I Need To Stop OR Cancel UILocalNotification

Tags: iphone, objective-c, push-notification, xcode3.2

I need to cancel UILocalNotification by Function but if i use

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

i get to the app again but the app stuck , it's timer

```
UILocalNotification *local = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    local.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:10];
    local.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    local.alertBody = @"";
    local.alertAction = @"";
    NSDictionary *customInfo =
    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"ABCD1234" forKey:@"yourKey"];
    local.userInfo = customInfo;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:local];
    [local release];


    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@""message:@""delegate: self cancelButtonTitle:@"Close"otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];



    [self performSelector:@selector(myFunc) withObject:nil afterDelay:10.0];

    startDate = [[NSDate date]retain];

    // Create the stop watch timer that fires every 10 ms
    myTime = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0/10.0
                                                      target:self
                                                    selector:@selector(updateTimer)
                                                    userInfo:nil
                                                     repeats:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

If by stuck you mean crash, then following the memory management rules you need to retain your timer. 
When there will be no need in timer anymore, invalidate and release it.